# query to get only one item from target column in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there any query to get only one item from target column? below didn't working?

```
App\Job::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->pluck('customer_name')->first()
```

I wish to get just one item name from 'customer_name'

Now Laravel 5.6 using...

Comment: This should do the trick `App\Job::withTrashed()->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->select('customer_name')->first();`

Answer (score 3):

When using eloquent, using `first` will give you a single item, the first record matching your query. You can then access the property on that item:

```
// This will give you an instance of App\Job (or null)
$job = App\Job::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->first();

// You can then access the customer_name property on the object
$job->customer_name;
```

If you only want to retrieve that single column when you run your query, you can pass an array of columns to `first`.

```
App\Job::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->first(['customer_name']);
```

Assuming you're using the `SoftDeletes` trait in your model, your query will automatically have an additional check added to all of your queries to ensure that `deleted_at` *is null*. So when you're doing `->whereNotNull('deleted_at')` you're adding an additional clause to ensure records are not null as well, so you won't have any records being returned.

If you want to look only at deleted records, you can use `onlyTrashed()`:

```
App\Job::onlyTrashed()->first();
```

Comment: Yeah, your query doesnt fetch the data OP is looking for as it automatically hides soft-deleted models. What OP has would work to do what they want if it weren't for the soft deleted model being hidden from the query by default.

Comment: Same goes with all the answers here. None of them address the real issue.

Comment: What happens in a query when the where statement includes `WHERE deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND deleted_at IS NULL` ?

Comment: I see your point, though it does make an assumption that the OP is actually using soft deletes. I've updated to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in method for this: `value('field')`

```
App\Job::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->value('customer_name');
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries, look for "Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table"

If you meant only one field but still as rows, you can use `->select('field')` instead.

And since you want only trashed items, you can use `->onlyTrashed()` instead of the not null check.

Soft deleting documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#deleting-models

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$job = \App\Job::selectRaw('customer_name')
    ->whereNotNull('deleted_at')
    ->first();
```

And use it like `$job->customer_name`

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Magnetic, can you show your foreach part. Single column or result don't need ```foreach()```